# Children element not stretch parent container with fixed height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

for some reason my child elements don't stretch to the main section which has a fixed height of 1000px.

I need to be able to have a fixed height off 1000px and max-width of 1000px. There's also a space between two divs. I need it to be more fluid and stretchy. Could anyone explain what is happening please? Thanks

```css
body {
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: green;
}

.main {
  height: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.contain {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.top, .bottom {
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}

.top img {
  background-color: red;
  height: 379px;
  width: 100%
}

.bottom {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 379px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="main">
    <div class="contain">
      <div class="top">
        <img class="img">
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>
          eoufiwueg
          </h1>
          <p>
          difhewiuhfiuwehfiuhweuifhweiuhfuiewhfiuhweiufhewiuhfuiwehfiuhweiufhiweuhfiuhewiufhweiuhfiuwehfiuhweiufhiuwehfiuwehfiuhweiufhewfiuhweifuhweiufhiuwehfiuwehfiuwehfiuwhefiuhweiufhwiuehfiuwehfiuwehfiuhweiufhweiufhewuhfiuwehfiuwehiufhewiufhiweuhf
          difhewiuhfiuwehfiuhweuifhweiuhfuiewhfiuhweiufhewiuhfuiwehfiuhweiufhiweuhfiuhewiufhweiuhfiuwehfiuhweiufhiuwehfiuwehfiuhweiufhewfiuhweifuhweiufhiuwehfiuwehfiuwehfiuwhefiuhweiufhwiuehfiuwehfiuwehfiuhweiufhweiufhewuhfiuwehfiuwehiufhewiufhiweuhf
          difhewiuhfiuwehfiuhweuifhweiuhfuiewhfiuhweiufhewiuhfuiwehfiuhweiufhiweuhfiuhewiufhweiuhfiuwehfiuhweiufhiuwehfiuwehfiuhweiufhewfiuhweifuhweiufhiuwehfiuwehfiuwehfiuwhefiuhweiufhwiuehfiuwehfiuwehfiuhweiufhweiufhewuhfiuwehfiuwehiufhewiufhiweuhf
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: How can it be fluid and stretchy with a fixed height? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Because "contain" has absolute position !

Answer (score 0):

add this css

```
.container {
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;/*add this property*/
    background: green;
}
```